# strange Report VIewer Error: Could not load file or assembly 'App_WebReferences.e8ik1wuc

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm connecting to a MS NAV 2009 web service in my asp.net 4.0 web application...every other communication with the web service works fine but when i try to create a report with the report wizard i get the error below:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'App_WebReferences.e2c6mdeb,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Copying the assembly to the Bin folder resolves the problem but then another error occurs and the app can't compile. Error:

> "The type 'eOnline.LessonsClasses' exists in both
>   'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cavendishwebonline\9db1de22\42dd86dd\App_WebReferences.zxqfnb5w.dll'
>   and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cavendishwebonline\9db1de22\42dd86dd\assembly\dl3\048caf7e\caa8a704_c13fcd01\App_WebReferences.e2c6mdeb.DLL'"

I would appreciate some assistance on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please change ajaxtoolkit reference in bin folder(updated version)

Comment: Thanks...i will try this and give you feedback as i haven't had the time to work on this project.